# How to resolve error, can't convert package X with RemoteType 'repository' to remote

Tags: r, devtools

I am trying to use devtools::build_vignettes() on a custom package and I am getting the following error message:

Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
can't convert package COREthemr with RemoteType 'repository' to remote

COREthemr is also a custom package which I have installed and am able to use just fine for individual functions. I am using R version 4.2.1 and devtools 2.4.5.

Here's my lockfile entry for COREthemr

```
`{
  "R": {
    "Version": "4.2.1",
    "Repositories": [
      {
        "Name": "CRAN",
        "URL": "https://pkgs.guidehouse.com/cran/latest"
      },
      {
        "Name": "CORE",
        "URL": "https://pkgs.guidehouse.com/core/latest"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Packages": {
    "COREthemr": {
      "Package": "COREthemr",
      "Version": "0.2.2",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "RSPM",
      "RemoteType": "repository",
      "RemoteSha": "6dbc274172b45588c0d5180f8d8fdc6c4aafafe0",
      "Hash": "dc7ea6f6826e84fab91ffbd3abe52df3",
      "Requirements": [
        "ggplot2",
        "gridExtra",
        "openxlsx"
      ]
    },`
```

Looking at the lockfile, I think the package should be installed from my CORE repository, not RSPM. But changing the Respository to "CORE" just resulted in the same error. As did removing the entry for COREthemr from my lockfile, and removing the lines for RemoteType and RemoteSha.

Comment: Reinstalling the package with `renv::install("COREthemr", rebuild = T)` and then running `renv::snapshot()` and `devtools::build_vignettes()` worked!